# php convert datetime to UTC

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc

I am in need of an easy way to convert a date time stamp to UTC (from whatever timezone the server is in) HOPEFULLY without using any libraries.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the [getTimezone and setTimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php), see the example

(But this does use a Class)

UPDATE:

Without any classes you could try something like this:

```
$the_date = strtotime("2010-01-19 00:00:00");
echo(date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$the_date) . "<br />");
echo(date_default_timezone_set("UTC") . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $the_date) . "<br />");
```

NOTE: You might need to set the timezone back to the original as well

Comment: You should just use `gmdate` instead of changing the default timezone to UTC. Because `gmdate` automatically uses UTC.

Comment: -1 because you don't want to change the global default timezone for this. It just asks for unintended side effects.

Comment: @Phill What is 'sz' here?

Comment: I think it should be "Y-m-dTG..." instead of "Y-d-mTG..."

Comment: Its not working for me in laravel project. Its return the same date

Comment: and the T should be 'T', the correct format is: date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sz", $the_date)

Comment: Seems like over kill to convert a single datetime to UTC. What's proposed converts all datetimes nearby to UTC. With all respect this probably has caused some bugs. The person who wrote the question specified one datetime. The answer doesn't match the question. I think this deserves an edit.

Answer (score 127):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to generate a timestamp from the given string (interpreted as local time) and use [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) to get it as a formatted UTC date back.

#### Example

As requested, here’s a simple example:

```
echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2012-06-28 23:55'));
```

Comment: gmdate() is one of those PHP functions I wish I had stumbled upon a long time ago. nl2br, anyone?

Comment: GMT and UTC are not always the same.

Comment: @JaySheth Practically, UTC and GMT are synonymous.

Comment: @poke To make your answer even more illuminating, can you show the output of your example code.

Comment: @NigelAlderton The output depends on the timezone settings of the machine running the code. But it will be something like this: `28.06.2012 23:55`.

Comment: Hell, the date string has specific time zone associated with it.

Comment: @Kannu Hell yes, as the question states, the parsed date string is supposed to be interpreted as the server’s local time, which is what `strtotime` does, and then converted to a date string in UTC. Remember that the Unix timestamp is *by definition* in UTC. So whatever timezone the server had, it is incorperated by the time you call `strtotime`.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Nope, because of the strtotime. I am working on an astrology software, and what if I want to check Leonardo Da Vinci profile? He borned in 1452. strtotime can not do anything with this. DateTime is the best for this.

Comment: @poke GMT respects daylight saving time, UTC does not and that's why it is used so you dont have to factor anything else in

Comment: @Necro I don’t know what exactly you are responding to there but technically, GMT is the timezone at UTC+0 *without* DST. BST is UTC+0 *with* UTC. So you could say that GMT does not respect DST but instead is only a timezone without DST.

Answer (score 85):

Using DateTime:

```
$given = new DateTime("2014-12-12 14:18:00");
echo $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e") . "\n"; // 2014-12-12 14:18:00 Asia/Bangkok

$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e") . "\n"; // 2014-12-12 07:18:00 UTC
```

Comment: The question says convert a timestamp to a timestamp, and DateTime doesn't accept a timestamp as input. You would have to convert it to a string somehow then convert it back.

Comment: DateTime does accept a timestamp as input: `new DateTime('@' . 1656627600)`

Answer (score 31):

Do this way:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)
```

or simply

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

to get "NOW" in UTC.

Check the reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Answer (score 17):

If you have a date in this format YYYY-MM-HH dd:mm:ss, 
you can actually trick php by adding a UTC at the end of your "datetime string" and use strtotime to convert it.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("2009-01-01 12:00"." UTC"))."\n";
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("2009-06-01 12:00"." UTC"))."\n";
```

This will print this:

```
2009-01-01 13:00:00
2009-06-01 14:00:00
```

And as you can see it takes care of the daylight savings time problem as well.

A little strange way to solve it.... :)

Comment: I truly don't understand why the OP didn't pick your suggestion `:D`

Comment: @php_nub_qq probably because it works by changing the timezone for the entire script, which might not be desired and could have unintended consequences.

Comment: @felwithe It wouldn't if yoy skip the first line, which is just for demonstration

Answer (score 12):

Convert local time zone string to UTC string.
e.g. New Zealand Time Zone

```
$datetime = "2016-02-01 00:00:01";
$given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));
$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
echo ($output);
```

- NZDT: UTC+13:00
          if $datetime = "2016-02-01 00:00:01", $output = "2016-01-31 11:00:01";
          if $datetime = "2016-02-29 23:59:59", $output = "2016-02-29 10:59:59";
- NZST: UTC+12:00
          if $datetime = "2016-05-01 00:00:01", $output = "2016-04-30 12:00:01";
          if $datetime = "2016-05-31 23:59:59", $output = "2016-05-31 11:59:59";

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_New_Zealand

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind using PHP's [DateTime](https://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) class, which has been available since PHP 5.2.0, then there are several scenarios that might fit your situation:

1. If you have a `$givenDt` DateTime object that you want to convert to UTC then this will convert it to UTC:

   ```
   $givenDt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
   ```
2. If you need the original `$givenDt` later, you might alternatively want to clone the given DateTime object before conversion of the cloned object:

   ```
   $utcDt = clone $givenDt;
   $utcDt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
   ```
3. If you only have a datetime string, e.g. `$givenStr = '2018-12-17 10:47:12'`, then you first create a datetime object, and then convert it. Note this assumes that `$givenStr` is in PHP's configured timezone.

   ```
   $utcDt = (new DateTime($givenStr))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
   ```
4. If the given datetime string is in some timezone different from the one in your PHP configuration, then create the datetime object by supplying the correct timezone (see the [list of timezones PHP supports](https://php.net/manual/timezones.php)). In this example we assume the local timezone in Amsterdam:

   ```
   $givenDt = new DateTime($givenStr, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
   $givenDt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I sometime use this method:

```
// It is not importnat what timezone your system is set to.
// Get the UTC offset in seconds:
$offset = date("Z");

// Then subtract if from your original timestamp:
$utc_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($original_time." -".$offset." Seconds"));
```

Works <strike>all</strike> **MOST** of the time.

Comment: Two problems here.  First you shouldn't subtract you should add the offset.  Second, this doesn't work if local timezone is currently on DST and the desired date is not on DST.  The offset would be off by an hour.  Or Vice Versa.  So yes, this works MOST of the time, but not always.

Answer (score 4):

As [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) requires specific input format, [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) could be used (**php 5.3+ is required**)

```
// set timezone to user timezone
date_default_timezone_set($str_user_timezone);

// create date object using any given format
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($str_user_dateformat, $str_user_datetime);

// convert given datetime to safe format for strtotime
$str_user_datetime = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// convert to UTC
$str_UTC_datetime = gmdate($str_server_dateformat, strtotime($str_user_datetime));

// return timezone to server default
date_default_timezone_set($str_server_timezone);
```

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 5 or superior, you may use **datetime::format** function (see documentation http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
 echo strftime( '%e %B %Y' , 
    date_create_from_format('Y-d-m G:i:s', '2012-04-05 11:55:21')->format('U')
    );  // 4 May 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php or if you need to not use a string but time components instead, then http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo date('F d Y', strtotime('2010-01-19 00:00:00'));
```

will output:

```
January 19 2010
```

you should change format time to see other output

Answer (score 0):

General purpose normalisation function to format any timestamp from any timezone to other.
Very useful for storing datetimestamps of users from different timezones in a relational database. For database comparisons store timestamp as UTC and use with `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

```
/**
 * Convert Datetime from any given olsonzone to other.
 * @return datetime in user specified format
 */

function datetimeconv($datetime, $from, $to)
{
    try {
        if ($from['localeFormat'] != 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
            $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($from['localeFormat'], $datetime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        $datetime = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($from['olsonZone']));
        $datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($to['olsonZone']));
        return $datetime->format($to['localeFormat']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

***Usage:***

> ```
> $from = ['localeFormat' => "d/m/Y H:i A", 'olsonZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta'];
>
> $to = ['localeFormat' => "Y-m-d H:i:s", 'olsonZone' => 'UTC'];
>
> datetimeconv("14/05/1986 10:45 PM", $from, $to); // returns "1986-05-14 17:15:00"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on [Phill Pafford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095812) (I did not understand his 'Y-d-mTG:i:sz' and he suggested to revert timezone). 
So I propose this (I complicated by changing the HMTL format in plain/text...):

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain;');
$my_timestamp = strtotime("2010-01-19 00:00:00");

// stores timezone
$my_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo date(DATE_ATOM, $my_timestamp)."\t ($my_timezone date)\n";

// changes timezone
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $my_timestamp)."\t\t (ISO8601 UTC date)\n";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $my_timestamp)."\t\t (your UTC date)\n";

// reverts change
date_default_timezone_set($my_timezone);
echo date(DATE_ATOM, $my_timestamp)."\t ($my_timezone date is back)\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to explain *how* this improves on Phil's answer. What did you change in the code, and why is it better?

Comment: Changing the default PHP timezone to convert two timestamps is a hack that works, but not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can try this:

```
<?php echo (new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore')))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e"); ?>
```

this will output :

> 2017-10-25 17:13:20 Asia/Singapore

you can use this inside the value attribute of a text input box if you only want to display a read-only date.

remove the 'e' if you do not wish to show your region/country.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get **UTC time** of **any timezone** set in user's local system (This will be required for web applications to save different timezones to UTC):

1. Javascript (client-side):

   ```
   var dateVar = new Date();
   var offset = dateVar.getTimezoneOffset();
   //getTimezoneOffset - returns the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time
   document.cookie = "offset="+offset;
   ```
2. Php (server-side):

   ```
   public function convert_utc_time($date)
   {
       $time_difference = isset($_COOKIE['offset'])?$_COOKIE['offset']:'';
       if($time_difference != ''){
           $time = strtotime($date);
           $time = $time + ($time_difference*60); //minutes * 60 seconds
           $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
       } //on failure of js, default timezone is set as UTC below
       return $date;
   }
   ..
   ..
   //in my function
   $timezone = 'UTC';
   $date = $this->convert_utc_time($post_date); //$post_date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   echo strtotime($date. ' '. $timezone)
   ```