# Converting a date time to gmt date using php

Tags: php

I have echo this PHP code

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d G:i:s");
```

Got this result:

```
2012-02-23 9:30:000
```

When i echo this PHP code

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime("2012-02-23 15:00:00"));
```

got the result

But the actual gmt time for this is `2012-02-23 9:30:00` but iam getting

```
2012-02-23 20:30:00
```

Any mistake i have done?

Comment: can you be more precise about what you want to do?  You want to add 5 1/2 hours to time values or not have them added?

Comment: If the time is 2012-02-23 13:25:17 i want to get it as 2012-02-23 9:25:17

Comment: You have tried mktime in substitution with strtotime?

Comment: What timezone is your server in?

Comment: Check this link may be help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771741/how-to-convert-datetime-to-gmt-in-php