# Change the time to UTC format

Tags: php, datetime

Example: In mysql db time is: '2014-09-15 14:48:00' this is canada time "America/Toronto"
I want to change this time to UTC format. PHP code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095703/php-convert-datetime-to-utc

Comment: You should show some code, you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set input timezone, and output timezone:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2014-09-15 14:48:00', new DateTimezone('America/Toronto'));
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimezone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/197876)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change time format using this function **date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');**

Here is list of timezone : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to specify the time into a specific time zone or state... 
 Use date_default_timezone_set()...

E.g:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```