# How to convert current IST time to UTC ? Also need to find the time one hour before that UTC time

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc

Need to convert the current time in IST (India Standard Time), stored in a PHP variable to UTC time, and store it to another variable using PHP.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$Present = date('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $Present; //to be converted to utc


$GMT = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($Present));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php convert datetime to UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095703/php-convert-datetime-to-utc)

Answer (score 1):

Use [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($Present));
```

following will decrease 1 hour

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($Present.'-1 hour'));
```

Comment: I also need to convert one hour before this time, in a variable. Code Updated above.

Comment: Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$Present=date('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $Present; //to be converted to utc

$date = new DateTime($Present);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Abidjan'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Explain your solutions please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the php built in [getTimezone and setTimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php),

```
$the_date = strtotime("2010-01-19 00:00:00");
echo(date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$the_date) . "<br />");
echo(date_default_timezone_set("UTC") . "<br />");
echo(date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $the_date) . "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and tested solution

```
$presentInst = new \DateTime(now('Asia/Kolkata'), new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$present     = $presentInst->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e");

echo $present . "<br/>"; // your local time i.e. in IST

$presentInst->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$utcTime = $presentInst->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e");

echo $utcTime; //UTC time
```

*Hope this helps*

Answer (score -1):

Please read this, it should solve your problem

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php

example :

```
$given = new DateTime("2014-12-12 14:18:00");
echo $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e") . "\n"; // your time

$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e") . "\n"; // UTC
```