# Retrieve date and convert it to specific time zone according to user time zone

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

i want retrieve date from database(s_start)  and convert it to Specific time zone like (Africa/Cairo) according to user time zone from database (s_timezone) i can only retrieve orginal date stored in database and i can't convert the result My controller code :

```
$this->db->select('s_id');    
$this->db->select('s_start');    
$this->db->from('sessions');

$query = $this->db->get($this->event);
    if ($query) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return NULL;
```

[image]

html code :

```
          <div id="cal-slide-content" class="cal-event-list">
          <ul class="unstyled list-unstyled">
        <% _.each(events, function(event) { %>
        <li>
            <span class="pull-left event <%= event['s_start'] %>"> 
         </span>&nbsp;
            <a href="" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>"
                data-event-class="<%= event['class'] %>" class="event- 
              item">
                <%= event.s_start %>&nbsp;<%= event.u_timezone %>&nbsp; 
                (<%= event.u_name %>)&nbsp;
                 </a>

      </li>
       <% }) %>
   </ul>
```

}

Comment: Save the datetime in UTC format. When user logs in, get current timezone and show it based on that

Comment: hi, i cant change to utc now in all application .current status now is user  can see date with his timezone stored in database but i want admin to see the dates with admin time zone also , how can i do it

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095703/php-convert-datetime-to-utc

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($result->s_start, new DateTimeZone($result->s_timezone));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Cairo'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') ;
```

Resources

- [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateTimeZone class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

**Edit** A function in the controller to convert timezones.

```
public function _convert_time($result){
    $date = new DateTime($result->s_start, new  DateTimeZone($result->s_timezone));
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Cairo'));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') ;
}
```

Now you can echo the result

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $this->_convert_time($result);
}
```

Comment: can i use mysql trigger to convert and save timezone in different timezone without php coding

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about mysql. :(