# How to select date in different timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I want to convert date to (Africa/Cairo) timezone in query result according to it's time zone stored in db
for example I want to get (s_start) and convert it from (Europe/London)to (Africa/Cairo) but in the select query itself(because I print event date from query result event.start).
My controller:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EventCalendar_model extends CI_Model {

function get_event_list() {
$aa = ($this->session->userdata(id));

$this->db->select('s_timezone,u_name,s_id,s_student,s_tutor, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s_start)*1000 as start ');    
$this->db->select('s_start as start');    

$this->db->from('sessions');
$this->db->where("s_tutor", $aa );

$this->db->join('users', 'sessions.s_student = users.u_id');

$query = $this->db->get($this->event);

    if ($query) {
        return $query->result();



    }
    return NULL;
  }



}
```

[image]

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073343/12731030) ?

Comment: my probelm is using jquery event calendar which get s_start from query result and echo it in js function so i need to echo converted timezone s_start from query result i cant echo php variable like $date.

Comment: You can create a function to convert time zones. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below Query will help you.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`s_start`, '+02:00', @@session.time_zone)) as africa_cario_time FROM `table_name`
```