# How to convert local date time into gmt using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am working with PHP,And trying to convert "dynamic datetime" ( can be with anytimezone) into "GMT Format", How can i do this ? I tried with following code but not working for me

```
echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2023-03-13 11:45 AM'));
```

How can i convert above "datetime" into "gmt" format ?

Comment: Use the DateTime class instead. Answer provided over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095703/php-convert-datetime-to-utc

Comment: To convert from A to B you need to know what A and B are. In the code you've shared, there's no clue about what the local time is meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much works out of the box:

```
echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2023-03-13 11:45 AM America/New_York'));
echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2023-03-13 11:45 AM Europe/Dublin'));
echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2023-03-13 11:45 AM Asia/Tokyo'));
```

```
13.03.2023 15:45
13.03.2023 11:45
13.03.2023 02:45
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/HF3vC#v8.2.3)

But your input does not contain any information about what the local time is meant to be, so PHP will default to [whatever local time you've set for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).